# Cannot use "parent" when current class scope has no parent in Magento/InventorySalesApi/Model/GetSalableQtyInterface/Interceptor.php

Tags: magento2.4.4

When I try to get products data with `$this->productRepository->get($productData['sku'], false, 0);`

same error with this as well.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(12382);
```

that time I got this error.